# pure-ftpd home directory

Tags: ftp, pureftpd

After installing `pure-ftpd` and adding a user using the command:

```
pure-pw useradd <user> -u <user> -d /var/www/domain -f /var/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd
```

pure-ftp asks me for a new password for the user. However, after logging in the user via ftp I can only do this using his linux password (and not the one set above). More, user is directed to his home at /home/ rather then given `/var/www/domain`.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you've forgotten to set your puredb path in your pure-ftpd.conf file or specify the auth mode in the launching command using the -l option (see the man page for pure-ftpd).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add user home as root(/) directory, just change the below option in pure-ftpd.conf which is available in /etc/pure-ftpd dir.

```
# Cage in every user in his home directory
# YES - User dir as root(/) directory
# NO  - No restriction 

ChrootEveryone YES
```

More details are explained in [SUSE11 FTP general settings](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_ftp_general.html)

Answer (score 0):

run

`ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/60PureDB`

to enable internal authentication method prior to UNIX authentication and PAM authentication

see [this page for details](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ftp.md)